# Powershell - set owner security group

Tags: powershell, file-permissions

Can I set the owner **and** the security group for a file using Powershell?
I mean, can I change for example `CVWINSERV1\None` to `BUILTIN\Administrators`?

```
Path   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\dev\lpeg.dll
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : CVWINSERV1\None
Access : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Users Allow  ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:S-1-5-21-704654959-829129038-1184563323-513D:AI(A;ID;FA;;;SY)(A;ID;FA;;;BA)(A;ID;0x1200a9;;;BU)
```

The whole scenario is this: I copy the file in Windows explorer under my account. After that, in my app (using Tomcat which runs under another account) I copy the file to the new destination folder, set the permissions and the owner. The permissions are set without a problem, as wel as the owner user, but I can not change the domain (?) of the owner. I thought it is sort of a symbolic link but it doesn't change at all.

Comment: Have you tried? Does something not work?

Comment: I'm using icacls like this: `icacls C:\dev\lpeg.dll /setowner BUILTIN\Administrator;`. Here I set the owner but the security group is still "CVWINSERV1\None". I think I'm definitely doing something wrong.

Comment: You're just setting the owner. For granting permissions use `icacls C:\dev\lpeg.dll /grant ...`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - yes, I'm using `set-acl` to set the permissions - and it seems to be no problem with it. The problem is concerning the group of the owner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Get-Acl` to retrieve the ACL, then call the `SetGroup()` method to set the group:

```
$ACL = Get-Acl .\path\to\file
$Admins = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount 'BUILTIN\Administrators'
$ACL.SetGroup($Admins)
$ACL |Set-Acl .\path\to\file
```

Comment: Thank you! Very important as the UI will only change the Owner and not the Group property which can leave the filesystem in disarray.